# JSF Bean validation not working

Tags: hibernate, validation, jsf, bean-validation

i have bean validation working if i try to save an object with incorrect values, which means an exception is thrown when i do a `Session.save` or `EntityManager.persist`, but the automatic bean validation don't work when i submit the form and there is some fields annotated with annotations like:

```
@NotEmpty
@NotNull
@Size
etc
```

I have added all the required .jar files from hibernate validator into my WEB-INF/lib, but it doesn't to work.

Is thee any special thing i should do?

---------EDIT----------
Here is the code of my page (this is the template)

```
<body>
    <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true"/>
    <h:form id="formPrincipalTemplate">
        <p:ajaxStatus style="width:40px;height:40px;position:fixed;right:5px;bottom:18px">  
            <f:facet name="start">  
                <p:graphicImage library="bmp" name="gifCarregando.gif" />  
            </f:facet>  

            <f:facet name="complete">  
                <h:outputText value="" />  
            </f:facet>  
        </p:ajaxStatus>

        <ui:insert name="conteudo">
            <!-- Aqui vai o conteúdo da página! -->
        </ui:insert>

    </h:form>
</body>
```

And here is the page itself (the button that should execute the validation is the one which the word "Gravar" on the value:

```
<ui:composition template="../template/adminTemplate.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="conteudo">

        <h:panelGroup id="atualiza">
            <div class="btnComandos">
                <p:commandButton value="Novo" actionListener="#{mbAdmin.novo}" disabled="#{!mbAdmin.notModoEdicao}" update=":formPrincipalTemplate:atualiza"/>
                <p:commandButton value="Alterar" actionListener="#{mbAdmin.alterar}" disabled="#{!mbAdmin.notModoEdicao}" update=":formPrincipalTemplate:atualiza"/>
                <p:commandButton value="Gravar" actionListener="#{mbAdmin.gravar}" disabled="#{mbAdmin.notModoEdicao}" update=":formPrincipalTemplate:atualiza"/>
                <p:commandButton value="Excluir" actionListener="#{mbAdmin.excluir}" disabled="#{!mbAdmin.notModoEdicao}" update=":formPrincipalTemplate:atualiza" onclick="return confirm('Deseja realmente excluir?');"/>
                <p:commandButton value="Cancelar" actionListener="#{mbAdmin.cancelar}" disabled="#{mbAdmin.notModoEdicao}" update=":formPrincipalTemplate:atualiza"/>
            </div>
            <br/>
            <p:tabView id="tabView" orientation="left" style="width:80%;margin:auto;" activeIndex="#{mbAdmin.aba}">

                <p:tab title="Consulta">
                    <p:dataTable id="admins" var="adm" value="#{mbAdmin.admins}" rowKey="#{adm.adminCodigo}"  
                            selection="#{mbAdmin.admin}" selectionMode="single">

                        <p:ajax update=":formPrincipalTemplate:atualiza" event="rowSelect" listener="#{mbAdmin.mudarAba}"/>

                        <p:column width="80">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Código" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{adm.adminCodigo}" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Nome" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{adm.adminNome}" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Email" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{adm.adminEmail}" />
                        </p:column>

                    </p:dataTable>
                </p:tab>

                <p:tab title="Cadastro" id="formulario">
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                        <h:outputText value="Código:"/>
                        <h:outputText value="Nome:"/>

                        <p:inputText value="#{mbAdmin.admin.adminCodigo}" disabled="true"/>
                        <p:inputText value="#{mbAdmin.admin.adminNome}" disabled="#{mbAdmin.notModoEdicao}"/>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                        <h:outputText value="Email:"/>
                        <h:outputText value="Senha:"/>

                        <p:inputText value="#{mbAdmin.admin.adminEmail}" disabled="#{mbAdmin.notModoEdicao}"/>
                        <p:inputText value="#{mbAdmin.admin.adminSenha}" disabled="#{mbAdmin.notModoEdicao}"/>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </p:tab>

            </p:tabView>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to ask this as a comment but my reputation is to low, for that reason i ask here.

Can you write things to your database over your application? Are the columns of your database same annotated like your entity file?

I never saw a .jar file in WEB-INF/lib therfore I use the "Dependencies" folder. To add sth. to this folder you rightklick the folder Dependencies -> Add Dependency, better you directly use a maven project there you can put all your dependencies in a pom file and maven will do the rest for you. The dependency for maven you'll find easy over Goolge, just search for "hibernate dependency". If you use a maven project you never take care about .jar files again. Just add the dependency for whatever you like to use and maven will download everything and put it in the right place that it is available in your project. The only thing you need to do is to fix your imports, after you wrote the code, that the packages are avaiable for your class. I hope this was more or less understandable?

Comment: Yes i understand, but as long as i'm concerned, there is no relation with database columns and bean validation, because it only validates the properties on the java side.

And about the .JAR's, this is a simple dynamic web application, i don't want to use maven on it, and in any way there must not be the problem, seeing that i have another application like this and the bean validation works...

Comment: Did you set the @Entity annotation over your bean?
Is hibernate startet by your application?

Comment: And you where right, the annotations don't need to match the row config. I checked that back.

Comment: Yes, the @Entity is present on the bean.

Comment: If you have the annotation over your bean and the correct .jar than the imports are in your entity? For shure you use the JPA 2? This is recommanded to bootstrap hibernate. Also I guess you already cleaned your project? The only site i can refer is [the hibernate hompage](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/) because now I'm really out of ideas. Could you provide a little more code or any error message (if dropped)?

Comment: No not the views, the entity where you use the annotations (atNotEmpty atNotNull atSize etc) :)

Comment: is there any reason why you use <body> instead of <h:body>?

Comment: Guess you already solved this, but i just wanted to point out that there is a bug where validation is ignored in Majorra 2.2.3+. So if you use that, try 2.2.2 or 2.1.x